# NS_ERROR_FAILURE with absent property

Tags: firefox-addon, xpcom

I trying to capture pageLoad event in progressListener, in onLocationChange i check URI of fresh page, and in case URI = about:blank i got

Error: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIURI.host]

As i understand this URI don't have host at all.

How can i check that host is available without raw parsing and exception catching? Is there any conventional way to check that atribute is present?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to filter certain protocols (filter on `scheme`).  It's best to use a whitelist in this case of the protocols you care about.

Answer (score 0):

In general there's no way to know for sure without doing a try/catch, but currently an `nsIStandardURL` is the only sort of URI that will have a host.

Answer (score 0):

When I faced this problem my solution was: 
To indicate an observer flag `aWebProgress.NOTIFY_LOCATION`

```
aWebProgress.addProgressListener(this.listener, aWebProgress.NOTIFY_LOCATION);
```

Before I had `aWebProgress.NOTIFY_LOCATION` and there was an exception you desc